# ¿Cómo hago para seleccionar el código y precio de la prenda mas barata?

Tags: mysql, sql

He probado con

```
SELECT id, min(precio) FROM ropa;
```

Pero me aparece este error:

> ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'TIENDA.ropa.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

se que si pongo

```
SELECT min(precio) FROM ropa;
```

Aparece precio mas barato pero y con el nombre?

Comment: ¿Qué error obtienes?

Comment: ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'TIENDA.ropa.id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Si me dejo, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Para añadirle el signo '€' he probado a hacer un concat SELECT codigo, precio FROM tuTabla WHERE precio = (SELECT CONCAT('€', MIN(precio) )FROM tuTabla); pero no es correcto

Comment: Si, a mi tambien me lo parece el problema es que me lo piden en un ejercicio, tengo que hacer una consulta y que muestre todo eso..

Comment: y con tu intento que error obtienes?

Comment: Ningun error me aparece Empty set (0.00 sec) pero no me aparece nada

Comment: Es que el concat no va en la subconsulta sino en el select principal, es lógico que no te de resultados pues en tu tabla tu solo tienes cifras y cuando lo haces de esa manera tratas de buscar la igualdad de algo así: `123 = $123`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes obtener el precio mas barato junto con otros detalles por medio de una subconsulta de esta forma:

```
SELECT codigo, 
       precio 
FROM tuTabla 
WHERE precio = (
                SELECT MIN(precio) 
                FROM tuTabla
               );
```

Donde:

- Eliges el código y el precio
- Mediante un WHERE evalúas que el precio seleccionado sea igual a lo que retorne la subconsulta

  - Dicha subconsulta tomará el valor con el precio mínimo registrado

Nota:

- Si quieres concatenar el símbolo de una moneda entonces eso debe ocurrir a nivel del SELECT principal, ya que si lo haces por medio de la subquery, entonces dicha condición (*la del where*) no se dará y no mostrará resultados, lo anterior debido a que tratarás de comparar los valores numéricos que ya tienes contra un valor numérico que le acabas de anexar un string.

Entonces puede quedar de esta forma:

```
SELECT codigo, 
       CONCAT("€", precio) 
FROM tuTabla 
WHERE precio = (
                SELECT MIN(precio) 
                FROM tuTabla
               );
```

Comment: Esta consulta puede, potencialmente, devolver varias filas, si hay varios artículos que coinciden con el precio mínimo registrado en la tabla. Lo menciono, no porque me parezca mal, sino porque podría romper procesos que están diseñados para una consulta que obtenga un solo registro, y el AP dice que quiere obtener _"el artículo con..." _ (en singular).

Comment: Tu respuesta está muy bien y no tengo un aporte significativo como para escribir otra respuesta, por eso dejé el comentario, ya que pensé que valía la pena mencionarlo. Un saludo. :)

Comment: @jachguate toda observación siempre es bienvenida, gracias.